# how can i put view's inside view's in titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have three view's, a main view and two child view

main view:

```
var viewMain = Ti.UI.createView();
viewManin.layout = 'vertical';
viewManin.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
viewManin.width = deviceWidth;
```

child view1:

```
var viewChild1 = Ti.UI.createView();
viewChild1.layout = 'vertical';
viewChild1.height = 'auto';
viewChild1.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
viewChild1.width = deviceWidth;
```

child view2:

```
var viewChild2 = Ti.UI.createView();
viewChild2.layout = 'vertical';
viewChild2.height = 'auto';
viewChild2.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
viewChild2.width = deviceWidth;
```

adding views to the main view:

```
viewMain.add(viewChilde1);
viewMain.add(viewChilde2);
```

inside each Child view i have labels with variable text size so i can't define the height of the view's. wen I add the child views to the main view what happens is that the last added view occupies the entire main view. how ca i make that the two view appears on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Manuel_Rodrigues! I think before you try to do that, you should take a piece of time to read the [API](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View) of titanium. It's had a good state to explain the property **Ti.UI.FILL**, **Ti.UI.SIZE** and **AUTO** in different situation for you to apply them. Here, I had wrote an example for you:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
});

var mainView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto',
    layout: 'vertical',
    horizontalWrap: true
});
win.add(mainView);

var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: '45%',
    borderRadius: 5,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    backgroundColor: '#25649d'
}); 
win.add(view1);

var viewLabel1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    font:{
        fontSize: 16
    },
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'left',
    verticalAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    text: 'this is a very long long long long long long text.'
});
view1.add(viewLabel1);    

var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    width: 'auto',
    borderRadius: 5,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    backgroundColor: '#25649d'
}); 
win.add(view2);

var viewLabel2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    font:{
        fontSize: 16
    },
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'right',
    verticalAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    text: 'yes, I had seen it!'
});
view2.add(viewLabel2);
```

If you run this code, it's should display like follow:

[image]

Comment: I discovered the solution after some time but thanks for the reply .